# Getting a list of all ID's on the site

Tags: wordpress

Sounds inane, but I think it would be handy to have an id list of the name of every element on my site. By every element I mean Posts, Pages, Comments, Users, the works. 
Id, Title
That's it.
I do not know how to loop through PHP code for this. My PHP skills are weak. Is this too ridiculous to answer? Maybe, but I'd still find it handy. I've looked through every Plug-in name and description that was close to fitting this task and found nothing.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The Loop is used by WordPress to display each of your posts. Using The Loop, WordPress processes each of the posts to be displayed on the current page and formats them according to how they match specified criteria within The Loop tags. Any HTML or PHP  code placed in the Loop will be repeated on each post. When WordPress documentation states "This tag must be within The Loop", such as for specific Template Tag or plugins, the tag will be repeated for each post.

For example, among the information The Loop displays by default: the Title (the_title()), Time (the_time()), and Categories (the_category()) for each post. **Other information about each post can be displayed with the appropriate Template Tags** or (for advanced users) by accessing the $post variable, which is set with the current post's information while The Loop is running.

**Simple Example**:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What you need to use is `the_id()` function. It displays the numeric ID of the current post. This tag must be within The Loop.

Put something like this in your loop

```
<p>Post Number: <?php the_ID(); ?></p>
```

References:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop